# Integrate Intercom with Ionic 4?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, intercom

I'm trying to integrate Intercom with Ionic 4.

The only documentation I could find is this for Ionic 3... 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/intercom/

I know it's for Ionic 3, and I'm using Ionic 4, but it was the only documentation I could find. When I tried implementing it, I get this error...

```
core.js:12501 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

Is it just not possible to integrate Intercom with Ionic 4 yet? Here is my code (simplified)...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Intercom } from '@ionic-native/intercom';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private intercom: Intercom) {

  }
  ShowIntercom() {
    this.intercom.displayMessenger();
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you integrate intercome in your ionic 4 app?

Comment: No, they don't support Ionic 4. But this was a while ago, so I'm not if it's changed.

Comment: Now, I also integrate this plugin and find a good resource. If I fix that then I'll provide you, my code.

Answer (score 4):

When using Ionic 4 and Ionic Native version 5 and above you need to import them with the "/ngx"

```
import { Intercom } from '@ionic-native/intercom/ngx';
```

Comment: also you need to list `Intercom` in `providers` list in your `app.module.ts`. (I managed to integrate intercom with ionic 4)

Comment: @ciekawy you didn't have issues with Android?

Answer (score 0):

At that time no. We decided to change customer communication provider (for business purposes) so cannot say anymore. I don’t think original problem is platform specific.